# Find $(a, b, c)$ that satisfies the system of equations $2a + 3b -4c = 7, a-b+2c=6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$\begin{align} 
2a + 3b -4c = 7, \\
a - b + 2c = 6
\end{align}$

I haven't seen a three-variable system of equations with only two equations before. I try to make the problem into a two-variable system.

Solving for $a$ in the first equation

$\begin{align} 
a = \frac{-3b +4c+7}{2}
\end{align}$.

Solving for $a$ in the second equation:

$\begin{align} 
a = b-2c+6
\end{align}$.

Then substitute the equations into $a$ for the original equations.

$\begin{align} 
2(b-2c+6) + 3b -4c = 7 \\
2b-4c+12+3b-4c=7 \\
5b-8c = -5
\end{align}$

$\begin{align} 
\frac{-3b +4c+7}{2} - b + 2c = 6 \\
-3b+4c+7-2b+4c=12 \\
-5b+8c=5
\end{align}$

This create a new system of equations:

$\begin{align} 
5b-8c =-5 \\
-5b+8c=5
\end{align}$

This leads to the solution $0=0$. So I assume this means I can select any $b$ and $c$. This however isn't the case, I can't find $a$ that satisfies both equations with this premise.

The problem additionally asks to solve for $b$ in terms of $a$ and solve for $c$ in terms of $a$. I did so using elimination.

$\begin{align} 
b = -4a +19 \\
c = \frac{-5a+25}{2}
\end{align}$

So we have both $b$ and $c$ depending on $a$. There is an infinite number of choices for $a$ so there are infinitely many solutions to this system.
Could I not find one or more ordered triples that satisfy both equations if I did not (following the instruction) create this final system of equations? Until now I thought the number of equations in the system was simply related to the number of variables.

Comment: +1 for very good work shown, regardless of whether your work has any mistakes, **which it doesn't**.  As your intuition suggested, 2 equations in 3 unknowns means (assuming that the equations aren't incompatible with each other) an infinite number of solutions.  Any choices for $(b,c)$ that satisfy $(5b - 8c) = -5$ can be used to generate a solution, by using one of the formulas that you derived for $(a)$ in terms of $b$ and $c$.

Comment: The geometric interpretation of your problem is to find the intersection of two non-parallel planes in three-dimensional space.  Since they will intersect in _a line_, any of the points on that line have coordinates $ \ (a,b,c) \ $ which satisfy the system of equations. Your result allows the computation of two of those coordinates if the third is specified.  (What you have is called an "under-determined" system.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, see my comment, following your query.

Since you are trying, not only to solve the equations, but also to express
$b$ and $c$ in terms of $a$, I would have approached it differently.

$$2a + 3b - 4c = 7. \tag1$$

$$a - b + 2c = 6. \tag2$$

Multiplying equation (2) above by $(3)$ gives

$$3a - 3b + 6c = 18.\tag3$$

Adding equations (3) and (1):

$$5a + 2c = 25 \implies c = \frac{25 - 5a}{2}. \tag4$$

Now, repeat the process to express $b$ in terms of $a$. 
Multiplying equation (2) by $(2)$ gives

$$2a - 2b + 4c = 12. \tag5$$

Adding equations (5) and (1):

$$4a + b = 19 \implies b = 19 - 4a. \tag6$$

At this point, you are actually done.  $(a)$ can be chosen to be any number.
Once $(a)$ is chosen, $(b)$ and $(c)$ are computed via equations (4) and (6) above.
Then, you have generated a solution $(a,b,c).$

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the equations for b and c in terms of a, then you are done. Just say that all ordered pairs (a,b,c) that work are in the form ($k$, $-4k+19$, $\frac{-5k+25}{2}$) for any real number k. If you plug back into the two formulas, you will see that they will both simplify to c=c for some constant c, meaning any value of k will work.